# Error:gas required exceeds allowance (9975570) or always failing transaction

Tags: web3js

I am trying to calculate the gas limit, to conduct an erc20 token transaction from 1 address to another and get this error:`Returned error: gas required exceeds allowance (9975570) or always failing transaction` can you help interpret it?

```
    let contract = new web3.eth.Contract(ABI, token_contract_Address, {
    from: Address
})
const acc_balance= contractInstance.methods.balanceOf(walletAddress).call(async function(err, result) {

    await web3.eth.estimateGas({

        "to": token_contract_Address,
        'data': contract.methods.transfer(fromAddress, web3.utils.toHex(result)).encodeABI(),

    }).then((value) => {
        console.log("gas limit: " + value);
    })
})
```

Comment: Does the from address actually have any tokens to send, on the chain you are using for testing?

Comment: @RobHitchens-B9lab I use the main network and there are 111 tokens on the walletAddress account.

Comment: @RobHitchens-B9lab can u help me?

Comment: @Madox What is your token's code? That error might be that some require is failing, accessing an array out of bounds, a revert, or the address of your contract is incorrect.